# Lifetime for a From trait implementation

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm having issues getting the lifetimes correct (again...) for a trait implementation.

There's a postgres [Row](https://sfackler.github.io/rust-postgres/doc/postgres/struct.Row.html) which I'd like to make convertible into my own structure like this:

```rust
impl<'a> From<&'a Row> for Video {
    fn from(row: &Row) -> Video {
        Video {
            video_id: row.get("video_id"),
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an error like this:

```
src/entities.rs:46:19: 46:22 error: wrong number of lifetime parameters: expected 1, found 0 [E0107]
src/entities.rs:46 impl<'a> From<&'a Row> for Video {
                                     ^~~
```

which doesn't make sense to me - the lifetime param is right there. What's missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lifetime is on the reference *to* the Row, but not the Row itself. To make a reproduction easier, I defined something that looks like a Row:

```rust
struct Foo<'a> {
    s: &'a str,
}
```

When we impl, we need to do this:

```rust
impl<'a> From<&'a Foo<'a>> for String {
    fn from(row: &Foo) -> String {
        row.s.to_string()
    }
}
```

Does that make sense? If you didn't have the reference:

```rust
impl<'a> From<Foo<'a>> for String {
```

Comment: Ok, just too understand it better I looked at the &str -> String implementation - it's `&'a str` and not `&'a str<'a>` - why is that?

Comment: A `str` doesn't contain any internal references, whereas `Foo` does. I _think_ that makes sense as an explanation? it may not.

Comment: Yes, that's great. Thanks for taking the time to answer all those SO questions Steve!

Comment: Any time! Other people spend a lot more time here than I do though :)